# My question was just closed, how could I reword it in order to get an answer?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, editing

[My question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/48751/my-clients-cms-just-added-civic-science-inc-polls-to-their-sites-without-permis) was just closed, and I realize the error of my ways.
I was asking a bit of an opinion question that would "likely elicit extended discussion or debate".

I guess I'd like to know if its uncommon for a CMS to add content to a site without permission?

I've run into this a lot with the current CMS I'm forced to deal with and I would assume that this isn't a common thing for a CMS to do.

How could I reword it in order to get an answer?

Answer (score 4):

Without getting into the specifics, it sounds like a permissions problem or an [CSRF vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery).

At one point in time or another, these have both been relatively *common* issues for a variety of content management systems - most site defacement is either spurious vandalism or (more likely) financially motivated.

Hopefully that speaks to the generalities your question concerns - don't know that it would be useful or appropriate to explore them further here, though you are welcome and *encouraged* to bring your concerns to the CMS provider for further discussion if an action was taken that was not authorized by one of the application's administrators.

Comment: In the long run, I'm trying to convince my client that they really need to switch to a new content management system. I was hoping that showing them that this sort of site vandalism was unusual and unacceptable would be a final coffin nail. Thanks. I'll drop it here, and go after the CMS.